# IFileOpenDialog pointer is null when it calls from CFileDialog

Tags: c++, mfc, cfiledialog

I was trying to wrap `CFileDialog` and `IFileOpenDialog` in a class, here is the code:

```
class ITest
{
    public:
    virtual ~ITest(){};

    virtual INT_PTR DoModal() = 0;

    virtual IFileOpenDialog* GetDlg() = 0;
};

class test : public ITest
{
public:
   test(BOOL bOpenFileDialog, // TRUE for FileOpen, FALSE for FileSaveAs
       LPCTSTR lpszDefExt = NULL,
       LPCTSTR lpszFileName = NULL,
       DWORD dwFlags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT,
       LPCTSTR lpszFilter = NULL,
       CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL,
       DWORD dwSize = 0,
       BOOL bVistaStyle = FALSE)
   {
       dlg = new CFileDialog(bOpenFileDialog, lpszDefExt, lpszFileName, dwFlags, lpszFilter, pParentWnd, dwSize, bVistaStyle);
   };
   ~test(){};

   INT_PTR DoModal(){ return S_OK; };

   IFileOpenDialog* GetDlg(){ return dlg->GetIFileOpenDialog(); };
private:
   CFileDialog* dlg;
};
```

Then when I call it like:

```
ITest* a = new test(TRUE, NULL, 0, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_NOVALIDATE, LoadResourceString(IDS_MYSTRING), this);

fdlg = a->GetDlg();

fdlg->Show(NULL);//it crashes here since fdlg is NULL
```

Then I tried to call `CFileDialog` and `IFileOpenDialog` directly:

```
IFileOpenDialog* fdlg = NULL;

CFileDialog* b = new CFileDialog(TRUE, NULL, 0, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_NOVALIDATE, LoadResourceString(IDS_MYSTRING), this);

fdlg = b->GetIFileOpenDialog();

fdlg->Show(NULL);
```

This part of code works perfectly.
Anyone knows why the crash happens ?
It confuses me so much since I feel they are so similar.

```
class test : public ITest
{
public:
test(BOOL bOpenFileDialog, // TRUE for FileOpen, FALSE for FileSaveAs
    LPCTSTR lpszDefExt = NULL,
    LPCTSTR lpszFileName = NULL,
    DWORD dwFlags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT,
    LPCTSTR lpszFilter = NULL,
    CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL,
    DWORD dwSize = 0,
    BOOL bVistaStyle = FALSE)
{
    dlg = new CFileDialog(bOpenFileDialog, lpszDefExt, lpszFileName, dwFlags, lpszFilter, pParentWnd, dwSize, bVistaStyle);
};
~test(){};

INT_PTR DoModal(){ return S_OK; };

IFileOpenDialog* GetDlg();
private:
CFileDialog* dlg;
};

IFileOpenDialog* test::GetDlg()
{ 
return dlg->GetIFileOpenDialog(); 
};
```

The above code also doesn't work( it defines IFileOpenDialog* GetDlg(); outside of the class declartion)

Comment: @Ripi2 sorry, i didn;t get your point. What do you mean IFileOpenDialog* GetDlg(){... is a global function ? It is non-static member function, if I call it ITest* a = new test(TRUE, NULL, 0, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_NOVALIDATE, LoadResourceString(IDS_FILTER_PLATE_AND_TUBE_EXPERIMENT), this);

 fdlg = test::GetDlg();   The visual studo will complaint that I am calling non static function.

Comment: I did implement it in the derived "test" class.        IFileOpenDialog* GetDlg(){ return dlg->GetIFileOpenDialog(); }; "You used a global instead.", I still don't get your point.

Comment: You would get debug message explaining the problem is that Visual Style is not enabled. Anyway, this class is complicated, just use `CFileDialog` with `DoModal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7.aspx#cfiledialog__getifileopendialog):

> Use this function only under Windows Vista with an object that has
>   bVistaStyle set to true. This function returns NULL if the CFileDialog
>   is not an Open dialog box or if bVistaStyle is set to false.

When you construct your `test` object:

```
ITest* a = new test(TRUE, NULL, 0, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_NOVALIDATE, LoadResourceString(IDS_MYSTRING), this);
```

you are leaving our the last parameter of your constructor, `bVistaStyle`, which defaults to `FALSE`. So just add it:

```
ITest* a = new test(TRUE, NULL, 0, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_NOVALIDATE, LoadResourceString(IDS_MYSTRING), this, 0, 
               TRUE); // bVistaStyle
```